# Failure to open file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a file residing in:

```
/public_html/funding_manager/application/uploads
```

called Funding_calendar_05_Dec_14.ics

I am trying:

```
fopen("/public_html/funding_manager/application/uploads/" . $upload_data['file_name'], 'r'
```

From within a Codeigniter conroller method but I get gold the file can't be found.

```
/public_html/funding_manager/application/uploads/Funding_calendar_05_Dec_1414.ics
```

I can't seem to get my head around this...

Any thoughts?

Comment: check for permissions, actual file exists and thread lock..

Comment: What error are you getting?  You must be getting something in your error_reporting or log.  Also, is /public_html the httpd document root or the server filesystem root?

Comment: Check if the given path `is_file()`, then whether is it `is_readable` and if both are ok - you `fopen` it. In case the file exists and is NOT readable, you have insufficient permissions to access it. Also, post errors that you're getting.

Comment: USE `FCPATH` to get the absolute url of your application, instead of this hard coded.

Comment: try codeigniter file helper it will make really easy to read and write files check documentation here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html

Comment: You can use APPPATH too as well as FCPATH, which gives you the absolute URL of your application directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FCPATH` should work great to get the absolute path of the file.

```
fopen( FCPATH."/application/uploads/" . $upload_data['file_name'], 'r' )
```

instead of hardcoded

```
fopen("/public_html/funding_manager/application/uploads/" . $upload_data['file_name'], 'r'
```